# Photoshop bulk background removal

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

I have to edit multiple product photos. I am looking for a script / automation to do this for multiple pictures at once. Ive read a lot, but i cant find the right answer.

The Products are colorful and pictured in front of a white wall, so they all have clean edges.
I have to save them as .jpg with a solid white background color.

Could someone tell me how to do this?
It would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120726/batch-background-removal-on-non-uniform-images

Comment: This question should probably be edited to include some more actionable information. We cant really help you as such since theres no concrete actions that we dont know what your actual problem is.